# Asp.net - New Window is closing when script alert shows

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hello I have a web application developed in asp.net. I have 2 web forms WebForm1 and WebForm2. In WebForm1 I had a button that will go to WebForm2.

Here is my code for that step.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('WebForm2.aspx','_blank');</script>");
```

In WebForm 2 I had a script that show message like Messagebox in windows form

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Msg.');" + "window.close();</script>");
```

Now everytime i close the message box my WebForm2 also closed.

Is there a way that I can show messagebox.

Comment: Then why you write window.close() in your script?

Comment: Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Msg.');"</script>");

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Msg.');"</script>");
```